# Sending object on AJAX call to WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to send a JSON object to a C# method, and return a different (also JSON) object.

The object is created in JavaScript:

```
    lottery = {
        TotalValue: totalValue,
        Players: txtPlayers.value,
        TicketPrice: txtAmount.value,
        FirstPrize: prize,
        MyComission: myComission,
        MyRate: myRate,
        SellerComission: sellerComission,
        SellerRate: sellerRate
    }
```

Then it's sent via AJAX:

```
function CreateLottery(lottery) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'default.aspx/Create',
    data: lottery,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status)
    },
    error: alert("error!")
 });
}
```

The C# code-behind (i have breakpoint and it never reaches here):

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static object Create(Lottery lottery)
    {
        return new
        {
            foo = "bar",
        };
    }
    public class Lottery
    {
        public decimal TotalValue { get; set; }
        public decimal Players { get; set; }
        public decimal TicketPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal FirstPrize { get; set; }
        public decimal MyComission { get; set; }
        public decimal MyRate { get; set; }
        public decimal SellerComission { get; set; }
        public decimal SellerRate { get; set; }
    }
```

Why i get always the "error!" alert?

Comment: "Why there is always error?" - What error would that be, exactly?

Comment: check answer and tell to me it is working or not.

Comment: I've edited the question, no need to downvote. It is a legitimate question, something particular is happening, and i am asking for help, not for anyone to do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Stringify your data first:

```
var lottery = {
    TotalValue: totalValue,
    Players: txtPlayers.value,
    TicketPrice: txtAmount.value,
    FirstPrize: prize,
    MyComission: myComission,
    MyRate: myRate,
    SellerComission: sellerComission,
    SellerRate: sellerRate
}

function CreateLottery(lottery) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'default.aspx/Create',
    data: JSON.stringify(lottery),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error!");
    }
 });
}
```

**Edit:** your error callback is defined incorrectly and will trigger every time the ajax call is made. Modify as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed what you said, but i still get "error!". Is it possible the problem is that some values aren't being sent as decimal (numeric), as the Lottery class values expect?

Answer (score 0):

you can send data to web method, have two type of **methods** are given below.

**Method 1**

You can pass each properties value in web method like as

```
function CreateLottery(lottery) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'default.aspx/Create',
    data: {'TotalValue': totalValue, 'Players': txtPlayers.value,'TicketPrice': txtAmount.value, 'FirstPrize': prize,     'MyComission': myComission, 'MyRate': myRate, 'SellerComission': sellerComission, 'SellerRate': sellerRate},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status)
    },
    error: alert("error!")
 });
}
```

**Method 2**

Change your array object to string using `JSON.stringify(lottery)`.

```
var lottery = {
    TotalValue: totalValue,
    Players: txtPlayers.value,
    TicketPrice: txtAmount.value,
    FirstPrize: prize,
    MyComission: myComission,
    MyRate: myRate,
    SellerComission: sellerComission,
    SellerRate: sellerRate
}


function CreateLottery(lottery) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'default.aspx/Create',
    data: JSON.stringify(lottery),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status)
    },
    error: alert("error!")
 });
}
```

Comment: I did that, also fixed the error callback as shown in the other answer, but still get "error!". I tried both your methods. Is it possible that the problem is the data isn't being sent as decimal (numeric) as the Lottery class expects?